# how to provide output of one model to another model as an input getting Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`

Tags: keras, keras-layer, tensor

```
def profiler(model, starting_layer_name, test_input):
# print(starting_layer_name)
layer_input = layers.Input( batch_shape=model.get_layer( 
starting_layer_name ).get_input_shape_at( 0 ) )
print( layer_input )

x = layer_input
for layer in model.layers:
  x = layer( x )
  intermediate_model = keras.Model( layer_input, x )
  start = time.time()
  intermediate_model = intermediate_model.predict( test_input )
  end = time.time() - start

def split(model, input):
 # this is the split point, i.e. the starting layer in our sub-model
 starting_layer_name = input
 new_output = input

 new_input = layers.Input( batch_shape=model.get_layer( starting_layer_name ).get_input_shape_at( 0 ) )

layer_outputs = {}

def get_output_of_layer(layer):

 if layer.name in layer_outputs:
   return layer_outputs[layer.name]

 if layer.name == starting_layer_name:
   out = layer( new_input )
   layer_outputs[layer.name] = out
  return out
 prev_layers = []

 for node in layer._inbound_nodes:
   prev_layers.extend( node.inbound_layers )

 # get the output of connected layers
 pl_outs = []

 for pl in prev_layers:
   pl_outs.extend( [get_output_of_layer( pl )] )

 out = layer( pl_outs[0] if len( pl_outs ) == 1 else pl_outs )
 layer_outputs[layer.name] = out
 return out

 if starting_layer_name == 'input_1':
  new_output = get_output_of_layer( model.layers[-139] )
 else:
  new_output = get_output_of_layer( model.layers[-131] )


 if starting_layer_name == 'input_1':
  model = models.Model( new_input, new_output )
  profiler( model, starting_layer_name, processed_image )


 elif starting_layer_name == 'block_1_project_BN':
  model = models.Model( starting_layer_name, new_output )
  profiler( model, starting_layer_name, processed_image )



split( model, 'input_1' )
split( model, 'block_1_project_BN' )
```

I need to traverse a pre-trained non-sequential model and splitting where branching is found in the model and dividing it into sub-models. I then need the output of model predictions result from the first model for the second model and from the second model to the third.

for instance Model A(output of last layers prediction result) -> ModelB

When the above code is compiled below error is raised

```
  Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`. Received: 
  block_1_project_BN (missing previous layer metadata).
```

Comment: @Emam I have written an answer, did it solved your problem?

Comment: Thanks, @Raj no the problem is not solved still struggling.

Comment: Ok @Eman, keep trying, will get back with the complete solution over your inputs.

Comment: @RajkamalSrivastav Can I have your email id for the solution you mentioned I need to ask some questions in this regard. Thanks

Comment: yes sure... rajkamalsrivastav5@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

Please see this example from custom layer section at [how to use block i.e. output of a layer to other](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers)
courtesy - tensorflow tutorials.

we created a class, which in itself is nothing but a block of resnet model, in which at the end, you can see identify function is also getting added.

```
Models: Composing layers

Many interesting layer-like things in machine learning models are implemented by composing existing layers. For example, each residual block in a resnet is a composition of convolutions, batch normalizations, and a shortcut. Layers can be nested inside other layers.

Typically you inherit from keras.Model when you need the model methods like: Model.fit,Model.evaluate, and Model.save (see Custom Keras layers and models for details).

One other feature provided by keras.Model (instead of keras.layers.Layer) is that in addition to tracking variables, a keras.Model also tracks its internal layers, making them easier to inspect.
```

```
class ResnetIdentityBlock(tf.keras.Model):
  def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters):
    super(ResnetIdentityBlock, self).__init__(name='')
    filters1, filters2, filters3 = filters

    self.conv2a = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters1, (1, 1))
    self.bn2a = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.conv2b = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters2, kernel_size, padding='same')
    self.bn2b = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

    self.conv2c = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(filters3, (1, 1))
    self.bn2c = tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization()

  def call(self, input_tensor, training=False):
    x = self.conv2a(input_tensor)
    x = self.bn2a(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.conv2b(x)
    x = self.bn2b(x, training=training)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)

    x = self.conv2c(x)
    x = self.bn2c(x, training=training)

    x += input_tensor
    return tf.nn.relu(x)

object of resnet class
block = ResnetIdentityBlock(1, [1, 2, 3])

def chain_blocks(input):
    x1 = block(input)
    x2 = block(x1)
    .... 
    ....
    return xn

so on you can bind up the resnet flow in sequential way within a function., moreover if you want to add another layer after a block you can do that, just make sure output shape of block should be same as input shape of next layer.
```

Let me know if you need additional information.